# Transforming cluster of points to polygon using Python

Tags: python, point, geopandas, polygon-creation, geometry-conversion

Having a GeoPandas `GeoDataFrame` with multiple points grouped into n clusters, I am looking for a way to transform a group of points into n or more clusters. Below is the sample image of points grouped into clusters:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.axis('off')
df.plot(column='k5cls', categorical=True, legend=True, linewidth=0, ax=ax);
```

[image]

The data is available: [here](https://situla.bitbit.net/filebin/77b2b25c070d081458cbf0e31096ef59b8c9e8a5c5a67108877d16f19b28701d/6a76c3e9ee0d056b1573960414300cadd925f7193d34109180f119b045346eb0?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=HZXB1J7T0UN34UN512IW%2F20220216%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220216T092009Z&X-Amz-Expires=30&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-cache-control=max-age%3D30&response-content-disposition=filename%3D%22test_df.json%22&response-content-type=application%2Fgeo%2Bjson&X-Amz-Signature=f2794faad7717b6ee1d9a45c47ea4135648b95d60a6a54522afa408188f77f18)

Does anyone know if there is a way to group these points into polygons in order to generate an image with colored regions instead of points?

Comment: Can you please share you input data for testing purposes with us ?

Comment: Thanks, I uploaded the data https://situla.bitbit.net/filebin/77b2b25c070d081458cbf0e31096ef59b8c9e8a5c5a67108877d16f19b28701d/6a76c3e9ee0d056b1573960414300cadd925f7193d34109180f119b045346eb0?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=HZXB1J7T0UN34UN512IW%2F20220216%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220216T092009Z&X-Amz-Expires=30&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-cache-control=max-age%3D30&response-content-disposition=filename%3D%22test_df.json%22&response-content-type=application%2Fgeo%2Bjson&X-Amz-Signature=f2794faad7717b6ee1d9a45c47ea4135648b95d60a6a54522afa408188f77f18

Comment: Data shows as Access Denied. <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<RequestId>tx000000000000001409199-006212732d-3a017752-default</RequestId>
<HostId>3a017752-default-default</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: In general I would recommend an aggregation with dissolve on k5cls, but its hard to say without the data. https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/aggregation_with_dissolve.html

Comment: Buffer - Dissolve

Answer (score 1):

Buffer - Dissolve (but this could change your outer lines).
Else try some plugins like "points2one"?